# Como não usar tantas Activities?

Tags: android, android-activity, layout

Olá, estou começando a programar algo no android faz alguns dias (um programinha de identificação de conchas, bem simples, porém extenso, nele você tem 5 opções, dentro dessas 5 mais algumas dependendo da especie, e dentro mais opções até chegar em uma concha específica com todas as informações dela), então eu fui criando layouts e activities pra cada espécie, classe, etc... acabou que deu umas 200 layouts e activities e ainda não cheguei no fim do programa kkkk e só aí que eu pensei "tem algo errado nisso" hehe. Então gostaria de saber se tem algum outro jeito de fazer um programa desse tipo com opções dentro de opções, totalmente offline, sem usar tantas activities e layouts.

Comment: voce pode usar fragments... dialogs personalizados... não necessariamente sempre activities... a forma de voce adaptar o codigo que vai dizer... se cada opção abrir uma pagina por exemplo e voce quizer apenas uma activity voce cria dialogs...  cada um abre uma "tela" diferente mas na realidade só tem 1...

Comment: A solução é utilizar Fragments, no limite, uma Activity pode ser suficiente para toda a aplicação.
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html
Os layouts poderás re-aproveitar, já a lógica poderá ter que ser reescrita.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara se eu intendi direito você tem um catálogo com várias conchas, e quer exibir elas em uma lista onde o usuário possa selecionar uma e ver os detalhes, certo? Se sim, você está indo pelo caminho mais errado fazendo uma activity/fragment para cada concha, pense comigo se voce tiver um objeto "Concha", você não poderia fazer um fragment para a listagem e um para o detalhe? Esse fragment de detalhe seria genérico e exibiria as informações de um objeto concha. Me corrija se eu não intendi a sua ideia, mas se a ideia for essa: "Exibir lista e detalhes de conchas" então você está na direção errada, se a ideia for: "Para cada concha eu quero criar uma certa logica diferente por exemplo espécie X faz uma determinada ação, espécie Y faz uma ação completamente diferente da X" ai sim voce deve criar um fragment para cada espécie. E se você não souber como armazenar essas conchas que não seja fixo em um fragment dá uma estudada sobre o banco de dados do Android. NO HARD CODE!

Comment: é mais ou menos isso, só que são opções dentro de opções. Por exemplo, pra Gastropoda eu tenho 3 opções Marinho, Terrestre e Agua doce, dentro de Terrestre tenho mais 19 opções que são as famílias, dentro de Marinho tenho 102 opções, e dentro de Agua doce mais 8 kkkk e ainda pra completar tenho mais uma média de 5 especies por família totalizando umas 500 espécies só em Gastropodas kkkk Teria um jeito de fazer tudo isso ser offline? ou seria um app muito grande?

Comment: Se você precisa de uma estrutura de hierarquia em árvore, pode usar um banco noSQL, ou guardar um JSON com essas informações. Eu aconselho criar uma aplicação para atualizar o banco de dados (ou JSON), se não você vai ficar maluco na hora de atualizar as informações. Tem como fazer em banco relacional também, mas aí sai do escopo da pergunta.

Comment: Sim Vanjura, você tem ai um erro de modelagem, você não precisa criar uma activity ou fragment para cada uma das 500 espécies de Gastropodas, e sim, você consegue manter isso até em um banco de dados relacional que é o caso do SQLite que o android usa, claro que isso gera um pouco mais de trabalho do que se você usar o banco noSQL como o Daniel sugeriu, mas pelo que vejo você está iniciando no desenvolvimento, então pra simplificar você poderia usar o banco relacional (SQL) e repensar a sua modelagem

Comment: repensar a modelagem seria tipo: Uma concha é uma entidade, quais atributos todas elas (as conchas no geral) tem? alguma tem algum atributo especifico(Só essa tem esse atributo)? eu preciso fazer uma herança? por exemplo: classe pai: Concha, classe filha: Gastropodas, entendeu? se fizer assim você vai acabar provavelmente com 1 activity e umas porção pequena de fragments que poderiam ser usados genericamente para todas as mais de 500 especies de conchas e ainda de quebra vai ter um codigo mais elegante e facil de se manter :)